# Twilio trial account restriction on verfied number?

Tags: twilio

is it possible to send a reply to verified number? 
its failing for me and I am not sure why.

here is my code. 
first the reply page.. 
sms.aspx..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="sms.aspx.cs" Inherits="CsharpTwilio.sms" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-9">
<Response>
    <Sms>Thanks for the message!</Sms>
</Response>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CsharpTwilio
{
    public partial class sms : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string From=Request["From"];
            string To=Request["To"];
            string Body=Request["Body"];


        }
    }
}
```

I found the problem I had the wrong encoding selected should have been UTF-9, moderator can close this as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

While the OP resolved their issue, you can always check your setup against [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml).

And if you'd like to dive deeper into unicode adventures and Twilio you can check out these posts.

1. https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/common-sms-problems-unicode-twilio.html
2. https://www.twilio.com/engineering/2012/11/08/adventures-in-unicode-sms